# tortoise svn fails to import to repository due to Inconsistent line ending style

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea, checkstyle

I was very excited to see that there is a check-style like plugin called [CheckStyle-IDEA plugin](http://code.google.com/p/checkstyle-idea/) for IntelliJ that i can enforce code style on the source.

I installed it using the IDE plugin repository, restarted it.
Unfortunately After pressing the *check this file* or *check project* I got the an exception (see log below).

I am using windows 7 pro,
IDEA  10.0.3 build #103.255 Build on April 2011
JDK 1.6.0_21

1. did anyone encountered this problem?
2. is there any other tool to do this job through the intelliJ IDE?

Thanks

2011-05-05 11:41:56,723 [1300492]   INFO - ea.checkstyle.CheckStylePlugin - Scanning current file(s).
2011-05-05 11:41:56,727 [1300496]  ERROR - style.checker.CheckFilesThread - An error occurred while scanning a file.
org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.exception.CheckStylePluginException: An error occurred during a file scan.
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.CheckStylePlugin.processError(CheckStylePlugin.java:409)
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.checker.CheckFilesThread.run(CheckFilesThread.java:72)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:703)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:813)
at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2189)
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.util.ScannableFile.parentDirFor(ScannableFile.java:72)
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.util.ScannableFile.createTemporaryFileFor(ScannableFile.java:58)
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.util.ScannableFile.(ScannableFile.java:40)
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.checker.CreateScannableFileAction.run(CreateScannableFileAction.java:60)at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:757) at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.checker.FileScanner.createTemporaryFile(FileScanner.java:228)
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.checker.FileScanner.checkPsiFile(FileScanner.java:167)
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.checker.FileScanner.run(FileScanner.java:80)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:770) at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.checker.CheckFilesThread.runFileScanner(CheckFilesThread.java:39) at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.checker.AbstractCheckerThread.processFilesForModuleInfoAndScan(AbstractCheckerThread.java:132)
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.checker.CheckFilesThread.run(CheckFilesThread.java:57)

Comment: What's the relationship between the title and the body of your question? You should change the title, as it doesn't describe your question accurately at all.

Comment: Such bugs should be reported directly to the vendors of the faulty plug-ins. StackOverflow is not another issue tracker.

Comment: 18 of 45 answers accepted is extremely poor. Not nice to fail to show your appreciation for people who help you. Also, this question is totally off-topic. You should address bug reports to the software author/vendor. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Checkstyle-idea plugin is sadly rather buggy :(

You can post or view issues at http://code.google.com/p/checkstyle-idea/  and get much faster support than here.

Comment: I have already done it. Is there any other way to enforce code style??

Comment: A suggestion that the product is buggy and they should contact the vendor/author isn't an answer; it's a comment.

Comment: It is the answer, because it should be accepted and the question closed.